# Updating Nav Bar background when displaying UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

In my `AppDelegate` I configure my navigation bar as follows:

```
func setupNavBar() {
    let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    barAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: appRed]
    barAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    barAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
    barAppearance.isTranslucent = true
}
```

This works well - until I want to display a `UIImagePickerController` from one of my `UIViewControllers` - the images go beyond the bar as its translucent - I need to be able to temporarily make the nav bar white, and then make it translucent again when the picker controller is dismissed:

[image]

I tried fixing this by adding the last two lines to the code:

```
 let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.allowsEditing = false
    pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
    pickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This doesn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
pickerController.delegate = self
pickerController.allowsEditing = false
pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
pickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And on image picker dismiss

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```